# Table row background-color not filling container in Edge/Chrome

Tags: css, vue.js, html-table, cross-browser, vue-cli

I have two tables, side by side, surrounded by a shared border. The last row in the first table contains a list with dynamically generated data (usually one word each). The second cell in the second table contains a list with dynamically generated data (usually 31 words).

In
[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILq6l.png), the table row color (light blue) for the first table extends down to the shared border.

Whereas, in [Edge/Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCrWF.png), the table row color (light blue) for the first table *does not* extend down to the shared border.

Is this a difference in how Firefox styles tables? Or am I missing a property in my code? I used normalize.css, if that makes a difference.

```css
<style>
/* general styles */
#generate {
  margin-top: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
/* button styles */
#button-generate {
  background-color: #76cef2;
  font-size: 8rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #93aef9;
  border: 6px solid #58efec;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px 100px 20px 100px;
}
#button-generate:active {
  background-color: #a29dfc;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #76cef2;
  }
/* table styles */
.table {
  margin: 5%;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #b18dff;
  border: 4px solid #000000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  table-layout: auto;
  width: auto;
}
.table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #93aef9;
}
.table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #85bef6;
}
.table td {
  border: 4px solid #a29dfc;
  padding: 2%;
}
.table td:focus {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#purple-background-bold {
  background-color: #93aef9;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* list styles */
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.6;
}
.list li:focus {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#two-column-list {
  columns: 3;
  -webkit-columns: 3;
  -moz-columns: 3;
}
#bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="table">
      <table v-show="isGenerated">
        <tr>
          <td id="bold">Cat1:</td>
          <td>{{ stuff1 }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="bold">Cat2:</td>
          <td >{{ stuff2 }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td id="bold">Cat3:</td>
          <td>{{ stuff3 }}</td>
          <ul class="list">
            <li>Cat4: {{ stuff4 }}</li>
            <li>Cat5: {{ stuff5 }}</li>
            <li>Cat6: {{ stuff6 }}</li>
          </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table v-show="isGenerated">
        <tr>
          <td id="purple-background-bold">Generated List</td>
          <td>
          <ul class="list" id="two-column-list">
            <li v-for="(item, index) in listItems" :key="index">{{ index + 1 }}. {{ item }}</li>
          </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Chrome canary (Chrome v92) does the same as Firefox.

Comment: @Alohci - thank you for the suggestion, but I do need the website to have consistent styling among all browsers.